# Not able to login to vmware esxi 5.5 after update, I can SSH in and use the console but no vSphere

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I tried to update my workshop server from ESXi 5.1 to 5.5. Now when trying to login using vSphere Client it won't connect. I am trying to connect directly to the IP address of the server. Here are some screenshot of the errors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try: `https://ip.address.here:9443/vsphere-client/`

Comment: This does not work as I do not have the web vsphere client installed. Is there way to install it?

Comment: It's supposed to come with 5.5 automatically. Hmm.

Comment: Any ideas? I tried it from a different computer but no luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try logging in via the console and running `/sbin/services.sh restart` to restart the management services.

Attempt your vSphere client connection after that's done.

Comment: I did this, and still no luck. I have restarted the server and I still am unable to. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure. Try a different browser/client computer, just to make sure.

Comment: Tried it from another computer and installed VSphere Client and it started working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked as correct above is not correct.

The vSphere client is no longer compatible with Windows XP because it uses increased cypher strengths not available in Windows XP. Later versions of windows will work, and there is a hotfix available for Windows 2003 server machines that fall foul of this change.

See: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2031053

Comment: It is possible to set the server to accept all cyphers. See: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2049143